# how to set select option if selected on submit in ci ,options value fetching from the database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to set select option if selected on submit in ci ,options value fetching from the database?
i have tried it but it didn't work!
can anyone tell me the solution?

this is my controller

```
 public function add(){

    $this->pageAction = 'Add';

    $error = array ();

    $finalData = array ();

    if($this->input->post('doAct') == strtolower($this->pageAction)){



        $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $finalData['error'] = "error";
        }else{

            $data = array (
             'c_id'=>$this->input->post('country'),
             'name'=>$this->input->post('city'),
             'active'=>$this->input->post('status')
            );



            if($this->main_manager->insert($data, "city") == false){

                $finalData['error'] = 'Cannot save data. Please try again.';
            }else{

                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'The data has been added successfully');

                redirect(SITE_ADMIN_URL . "city_admin/index");
            }
        }
    }
    $finalData['country'] = $this->main_manager->select_all('country');
    $this->load->view('administrator/header');

    $this->load->view('administrator/add_city', $finalData);

    $this->load->view('administrator/footer');
}
```

this is my view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="" id="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo SITE_ADMIN_URL;?>city_admin/add"/>

                    <div class="control-group">

                        <label class="control-label" for="form-field-1">Country Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="country">
                                <option value="">Please Select Country</option>
                                <?php
                                for($a = 0; $a < count($country); $a++){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $country[$a]['id'];?>"><?php echo $country[$a]['name'];?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                $select = "";
                                if($country == "selected"){
                                    $country = $select;
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $select[$a]['id'];?>"><?php echo $select[$a]['name'];?></option>
                                <?php }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <!--<input type="text" id="reason" name="country" value="<?php // echo set_value('country');  ?>" />-->

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">

                        <label class="control-label" for="form-field-1">City</label>

                        <div class="controls">

                            <input type="text" id="reason" name="city" value="<?php echo set_value('city');?>" />

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">

                        <label class="control-label" for="form-field-1">Status</label>

                        <div class="controls">


                            <input type="radio" name="status" id="status" value="1" <?php echo set_radio('status', '1');?>>

                            <span class="lbl">&nbsp;Active</span>

                            <input type="radio" name="status" id="status" value="0" <?php echo set_radio('status', '0');?>>

                            <span class="lbl">&nbsp;Inactive</span>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="space-4"></div>

                    <div class="form-actions">

                        <input type="hidden" name="doAct" value="add">

                        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit">

                            <i class="icon-ok bigger-110"></i>

                            Submit

                        </button>

                        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

                        <button class="btn" type="reset">

                            <i class="icon-undo bigger-110"></i>

                            Reset

                        </button>

                    </div>

                    </form>
```

Comment: Can you show us a var_dump() of $country please.

Comment: please explain your question clearly.  "set select option" means what?

Comment: thankyou for rplying me :)
set select means that option which was selected while submiting form like in country drop down menu i select pakistan option and then i submit it

Comment: i did it by set select function ! i did like this

<option value="<?php echo $country[$a]['id'];?>" <?php echo set_select('country', $country[$a]['id']);?> ><?php echo $country[$a]['name'];?></option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I don't see where do you define the default value as you only send the `$country` array to your view. 
For the example, we'll suppose that we have a var called `$default_value` in available in your view.

If you want to keep building your form without using the form_helper :

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="">Please Select Country</option>
    <?php foreach ($country as $c): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $c->id ?>" <?php echo ($c->id == $default_value)?'selected="selected"':''?>><?php echo $c->name?></option>    
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

But you can also use the form_helper :

1/ In your controler prepare an array that will populate your select

```
$data["countryArray"] = array(
              '-1'    => 'Please Select Country',
              '1'  => 'Australia',
              '2'  => 'France',
              '3'  => 'Belgium',
              '4' => 'Brasil',
            );
```

And then in your view :

```
echo form_dropdown('country', $countryArray, set_value($default_value', '-1'));
//First param : name attribute | second param : array containing <options> | third param : default value
```

Comment: Thankyou for rplying me i did it by using set select function ! 
 <option value="<?php echo $country[$a]['id'];?>" <?php echo set_select('country', $country[$a]['id']);?> ><?php echo $country[$a]['name'];?></option>